# API load testing, performance testing, Azure API app

Tags: api, performance-testing, load-testing, azure-api-apps

I am very new at testing stuff.

Now I have deployed **Spring boot Rest API App** on **Azure App Service**.

What my API does is that getting requests from **2 or 3 fixed clients** meaning which is opened only for **designated clients**, and my API retrieves data from **Azure Table Storage** and give them responses.

Here are **requirements**:

> ```
> 1. 1000 requests per second
> 2. 200ms for average response time
> ```

The **first question** is how to make **1000 requests per one second** (I tried to use JMeter for the test, but could not find out).

The **second question** is how to measure or find out how many requests my API app in Azure can take per second as well.

How can I get tested?

And one more question, can I say a number of the user is fixed and say "User load" is 2 or 3, and those 2 or 3 clients are making 1000 requests per second together.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a load testing tool, I would recommend the following ones:

1. [SoapUI](http://soapui.org/) - a de-facto standard for API testing, it has [load testing capabilities](https://www.soapui.org/Load-Testing/concept.html)
2. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) - multiprotocol load testing tool, [can be used for API testing as well](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter), can be run in clustered mode and provides better reporting

Both are free and open source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://loader.io/, a free load testing service that allows you to stress test your web-apps & apis with thousands of concurrent connections.

Comment: yeah, seems like their free trial is enough for me

Answer (score 0):

As per your **three questions** I will try to explain a little about how those objectives of yours can be reached using **JMeter**:

**Answer 1:**

**Concurrency in transaction level** can be reached by using [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) a JMeter plugin.

From BlazeMeter [Blog on Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers)

> **A Constant Throughput Timer** can pause the threads in order that a
>   goal-oriented scenario could be implemented. **Goal-oriented scenario** is
>   a load test type where the target is **not to simulate X concurrent
>   users**, but **X requests per second**. A Constant Throughput Timer works
>   precisely on the **“minute” level**, so make sure that your test lasts
>   long enough (1 minute or more) and you use a reasonable **ramp-up time**
>   to avoid spikes (unless you’re doing some form of stress testing).

So using this plugin in your script you will achieve your target **"1000 requests per one second".**

**Though,**

> This timer allows us to keep **total throughput constant**. Of course, **if
>   the server is not able to handle such a load, the throughput will be
>   lower**. Throughput may decrease if **other timers contradict the Constant
>   Throughput timer.** Although the Timer is called the Constant Throughput
>   timer, the throughput value does not need to be **constant**. This value
>   can be **changed during a test**.

**Answer 2:**

Constant monitoring the test output. Tests should be done by increasing **`Threads or Users`** step by step or gradually and output should be observed. **Constant Throughput Timer** doesn't able to achieve the given **"Throughput or Requests Per Second"** if **enough Threads** is not provided in **`Thread Group`**. And **`Target Throughput(in Samples per minute)`** also be increased gradually. Not the target **`1000/s`** input from the first test. It should be reached gradually.

**Answer 3:** It depends on you script design. You could say:

> "User load" is 2 or 3, and those 2 or 3 clients are making 1000
>   requests per second

But **concurrency** in **thread level** can be reached by providing the **`Test Duration`** greater than **`Ramp-up time`**. So after reaching the **ramp up time** those **`Users or Threads`** will be concurrent. Though, configuring JMeter components properly is needed otherwise, **concurrency** may not be reached. You might find [this blog](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/07/09/performance-testing-concepts-what-are-concurrent-users/) useful.

Comment: Thank you for great answer! not easy to understand at one shot though : )  thank you very much !

Comment: Actually.. can i ask you a question again?

Comment: so the architecture(?) of whole project is that... actual users will request to API "A" and API "B" which are not mine and that API "A" and "B" will request to API "C" which is my API, in this case, in the point of API "C", there are only two Users(Connections) (API "A" and "B")?. im kinda confusing ...

Comment: So what i am wondering is that, is my API getting  1000 requests per second from two users or still i need to test that i have 1000 users are calling my API.